# the category of Boolean algebras with monomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, boolean-algebra

Is there a nice characterization of $$\mathbf{Bool}_m^{op},$$

the opposite category of Boolean algebras with monomorphisms ?

I've just learnt that $$\mathbf{Set}^{op}$$ is CABA, which looks inetersting for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, through the [Stone duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_duality) (see also [Stone's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras)). That is, if we write $\mathbf{Stone}$ for the category of [Stone spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_space) with continuous maps then there is a duality
$$
\mathbf{Bool} \simeq \mathbf{Stone}^\text{op}.
$$
I am not entirely certain if by $\mathbf{Bool}_m^\text{op}$ you mean $(\mathbf{Bool}_m)^\text{op}$ or $(\mathbf{Bool}^\text{op})_m$, but it is easy to characterise what happens in both cases.

Through the Stone duality $(\mathbf{Bool}_m)^\text{op}$ corresponds to $\mathbf{Stone}_e$, where the subscript $e$ stands for epimorphisms. In other words,
$(\mathbf{Bool}_m)^\text{op}$ is equivalent to the category of Stone spaces with epimorphisms.

Similarly, but even a bit easier, we get that $(\mathbf{Bool}^\text{op})_m$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Stone}_m$, the category of Stone spaces with monomorphisms.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to study the links you provided. Just FYI,I meant the first possibility with $e$.

Comment: I have an easy question about your [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras): What is used to prove the fact that $$\{x\in S(B)|b\in x\}$$ is a base, not just subbase? I'm missing some basic topology here!

Comment: @user122424 Let's write $[b] = \{x \in S(B) : b \in x\}$. The claim is that $\{[b] : b \in B\}$ is a base for the topology (so not $\{x \in S(B) : b \in x\}$, that would just be one of the sets in the basis). Clearly $[1] = S(B)$, so it covers the entire space. Also, an easy exercise on ultrafilters (the elements of $S(B)$) is that $[a \wedge b] = [a] \cap [b]$. So the above collection is closed under intersections and hence a basis of open sets.

Comment: In fact, another easy exercise on ultratfilters is that $[a \vee b] = [a] \cup [b]$ and $[\neg b] = S(B) - [b]$. So the sets of the form $[b]$ are in fact clopen (closed and open), and $[a \vee b] = [a] \cup [b]$ shows that the collection from my previous comment is also a basis of closed sets. This is in fact the entire idea of the Stone representation theorem: we find the Boolean algebra back as the clopen sets of $S(B)$.